# Installing and Importing PHP Modules

Tags: php, import, module, installation

1) I've written a few classes and interfaces that I want to place in the "automatically loaded classes" list, if such a list exists. In all, I have a folder containing 30 PHP file, each containing a class or an interface. How do I go about making them part of the default PHP library for my computer / server? As I'm sick of having to write an autoload on top of my PHP files.

2) Secondly, are "include" and "require" essentially the only way to import files? Is there a cleaner way to load classes from files, like "import" in Java? A way that doesn't simply add the file into the file from which include was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this ...

```
// autoloader
function autoloader($class)
{
    $filename = BASE_PATH . '/inc/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
    include_once($filename);
}

spl_autoload_register('autoloader');
```

Comment: Actually, that's what I'm trying to avoid :D. I want to make it so that the classes are part of the PHP library on my computer, like mysqli.

Comment: You are looking to build your own extension - http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/07/07/how-to-create-php-extensions-in-c-part-i-adding-simple-function/